# I try to connect with AWS Toolkit and with Remote-SSH extensions but neither work for connecting to my ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, visual-studio-code, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, remote-access

I have tried nearly every resource out there for connecting my VSC to AWS so that I can develop on my ec2 instance but they have all failed. I tried the official documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-vscode/latest/userguide/connect.html) with and without the help from this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e45DkxfDACM) and some other sources but nothing worked.
These are the steps I took for connecting to AWS with the toolkit extension.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**AWS Toolkit extension**

([the instance was already created before and it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9SR6.png)).

1. [I made an IAM instance with the following permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8P04.png)
2. downloaded the extension
3. [added my credentials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/laDov.png)
4. connected to AWS
5. [My AWS tab looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hecWX.png) and [my AWS explorer looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7Km4.png). Sadly no connections found.

**Remote SSH**

I have also tried using the Remote SSH and that did not work either. For that I will briefly describe the steps.

1. I downloaded Remote - SSH
2. Attempted to connect to my instance with:

> ssh -i "test.pem" ec2-user@ec2-18-FAKE-35-FAKE.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com

3. That opens a new window where I then select Linux and I get the following error

> Could not establish connection "...". The process tried to write to a non-existent pipe.

Again that did not work either.

I have no idea what more to do.

Comment: Before trying to get VS Code remote SSH to work, can you get regular command line SSH to work? Are you familiar with using SSH with EC2 (have you done this successfully in the past)?

Comment: (Jarmod) Yes, I have gotten a SSH connection to work.